# XMPP: How to query specific roster information by Jabber Id

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I'm beginner in XMPP. I'm using Strophe js library.

Now I wondering to get a **specific roster item by its jabber id**.

But I'm confused about what kind of stanza & property that I need to send.

I've got the way to retrieve my roster list by sending IQ stanza like this:

```
<iq from='juliet@example.com/balcony'
       id='bv1bs71f'
       type='get'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>
</iq>
```

But I got **all** contact list like this:

```
<iq id='bv1bs71f'
       to='juliet@example.com/chamber'
       type='result'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster' ver='ver7'>
      <item jid='nurse@example.com' name='Nurse'/>
      <item jid='romeo@example.net' name='Romeo'/>
      <item jid='abc@example.net' name='Abc'/>
      ....
    </query>
</iq>
```

My question is how to get the **specific item** (only one item result) by **sending my contact JID** as a parameter?

If I could explain by SQL the statement is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM roster WHERE jabberID = ....
```

rather than this:

```
SELECT * FROM roster
```

I want to get my contact **nickname** by its JID.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is this for a user in a room in muc or a room in muc or...?

Comment: this is for a user in general context, a user from my contact list :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a "to" attribute in your iq. If you are co-subscribed, should return name.

$iq({ type: 'get', from: myjid, to: jid }).c('query', { xmlns: Strophe.NS.ROSTER });

Comment: I'm sorry Mark, but it seems not working. I've sent 
`'<iq from='me@myhost'
    to='him@myhost'
    type='get'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>
</iq>'`
But the server doesn't give any responses

Comment: Your alternative is to loop through the roster and gt it that way.

Comment: That's imagined by me but I think it doesn't very efficient & I hope to retrieve it by stanza. But thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: if you're using the roster plugin for Strophe, once you fetch the roster, you just need to call connection.roster.findItem(jid). The "items" array is available until you change pages (along with changes the the roster).

Comment: Okay Mark, I've never known that Strophe has plugin before. I'll try, thanks :)
This is the plugin https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/roster right?

Comment: That's the one I'm referring to

Comment: I'm getting problem with strophe.roster.js plugin. The presence isn't up to date

Comment: @WillyLazuardi I am getting responce with item and groups under items. but only few groups i am getting. User A is in morethan 100 roster groups , but only geting 18-25

Comment: @sahal what server are you using? it is maybe the server issue

Comment: @WillyLazuardi The issue was with the length of group name . server will trill 50 characters. i am using openfire